# DownloadUrl for firebase storage not working

Tags: android, firebase, url, firebase-storage

I tried finding on a lot of stackoverflow questions,
and many other places, but could not find a working method.

I am uploading a picture to firebase storage, and on upload I want a download link for that picture/document.

`taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()` is now deprecated, 
so they have mentioned to use `getDownloadUrl` on the Firebase Storage Reference, or `getResult` on the `taskSnapshot`, but both return some jargon and I am not able to get a proper download url.

```
btnUploadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!ImageUri.toString().trim().equals(""))
                {

                    final StorageReference imageRef = mFirebaseStorage.child("some.jpg");
                    imageRef.putFile(ImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d("UploadSuccess", ""+task.getResult()+"\n"+mFirebaseStorage.getDownloadUrl());
                        }
                    });

                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Select An Image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

this gave me an log **Output :**

> D/UploadSuccess:
>   com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask$TaskSnapshot@fff6f13
>       com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@c781349

and the version of firebase/storage i am using :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
```

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can get the download url.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
val ref = mStorageReference?.child("some.jpg")
        val  uploadTask = ref?.putFile(Uri.fromFile(File(mImagePath)))

        uploadTask?.continueWithTask(Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>
        { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                task.exception?.let {
                    throw it
                }
            }
            return@Continuation ref.downloadUrl
        })?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val downloadUri = task.result
                mTempDatabaseReference?.child("image")?.setValue(downloadUri.toString())
            } else {
                // Handle failures
                // ...
            }
        }
```