# Cannot retrieving image url in firebase storage

Tags: java, firebase-storage

I get this strange URL, `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@424c4968` that is not my URL photo. To solve this He suggests me to URL convert into `String`. but why still not working?

> [Cannot retrieve images from firebase storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430319/cannot-retrieve-images-from-firebase-storage)

**this is my code that result the strange url:**

```
Task<Uri> download_uri = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
Map<String, Object> value = new HashMap<>();
value.put("image", download_uri.toString()); // i follow his suggestion to convert url into string
```

OUTPUT of download_uri `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@424c4968`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get URL from Firebase Storage getDownloadURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374868/how-to-get-url-from-firebase-storage-getdownloadurl)

Comment: @DougStevenson i am still not understand, which part of my code not working

Comment: Try my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55221038/7791183

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks there is no call back `onSuccess` or `onComplete` in my code .

Comment: @RajatMittal ..It help me

Comment: @BillGates Please Upvote answer.